# Add or substracting base on multiple condition of dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the first data set

| type | week | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 |
| A | 2 | -1 |
| B | 1 | 50 |
| D | 4 | -5 |

This is the second data set:

| type | group | week | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| A | 2 | 1 | 10 |
| D | 10 | 4 | 1 |
| D | 11 | 4 | 2 |
| D | 16 | 4 | 4 |

Based on the above data sets, according to the type and week in both data sets.

From set 1 if type = A and week =1 then add the value to the largest in set 2 which is type = A, group =2 week=1 the new value should be 20.
whereas when the value is negative eg, type=D week=4, then it should minus from the largest but can never go below 0. Else take away from the second largest and so on.

So the new data should be like this:

| type | group | week | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| A | 2 | 1 | 20 |
| D | 10 | 4 | 1 |
| D | 11 | 4 | 1 |
| D | 16 | 4 | 0 |

I am not sure how can i automate this process to make it general, the actual data is larger, and this is just an illustration. I am trying to do this on Python pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#use left join
df = df2.merge(df1, how='left', on=['type','week'], suffixes=('','_'))

#sorting for maximal values first per groups
df = df.sort_values(['type','week','value'], ascending=[True, True, False])

#create cumulative sums pre groups of values and add value_ from df1
df['val'] = df.groupby('week')['value'].cumsum().add(df['value_'])

#first rows per groups
m1 = ~df.duplicated(['type','week'])
#negative value_
m2 = df['value_'].lt(0)
#negative subtracted cumulative sum
m3 = df['val'].lt(0)
#first positive per groups after last nagative
m4 = df.groupby(['type','week'])['val'].shift().lt(0)

#final mask first part test first positive values per groups m1 & ~m2
#second part test negative values
mask = (m1 & ~m2) | (m2 & (m3 | m4)) 

#only for filtered rows add values of val with clip for convert negative to 0
df.loc[mask, 'value'] = df.loc[mask, 'val'].clip(lower=0)

df = df.sort_index()[['type','group','week','value']]
print (df)
  type  group  week  value
0    A      1     1      5
1    A      2     1     20
2    D     10     4      1
3    D     11     4      1
4    D     16     4      0
```